# Spyder fails to launch. Can not be launched from anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Checked all packages and upgraded to latest version. Tried uninstall and reinstall multiple times to no effect.

Trying to open with anaconda navigator gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 190, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 92, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```